# python socket programming: Crafting pim-join-prune packet

Tags: python, sockets, multicast, pim

Good afternoon everyone,

my coding skills are not quite on the level required to do socket programming myself and I was wondering if someone here can help me with what I need - which is fairly simple:

- crafting own PIM (multicast) join packet.

I want to send a "dummy" PIM join packets to a neighbouring device without really bothering maintaining any PIM adjacencies/(hellos). Ideally I want to end-up with a function that accepts a few arguments:

```
def send_dummy_join(group, rp, source_ip):
  // send 1 join every time this function is called
```

Ideally I need it to run using python3 not using external modules (e.g. scapy)

Another problem I have & don't quite understand how to solve is crafting a packet with a source address which doesn't belong to any network interface on the system. I know scapy can do this I only don't quite understand how to craft it myself.

Thanks in advance for all your help. Much appreciated!

Some external information.

## PIM headers

http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/pim.htm

## PIM.c implementation

https://github.com/troglobit/pimd/blob/master/src/pim.c

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, exactly?

Comment: By the look of it right now we need to fix the checksum calculation. Is this something you can help with?

Comment: Fair enough. We have some solid base to work on now so if you're willing to help - please do so, it will be highly appreciated. Unless you're here simply to tell people off..

Comment: Sure, I’ll give it a try :)

Comment: So I thought...

Comment: _So I thought..._ Pardon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will most probably (*fully rightfully though ;-)*) get publicly lynched for the following piece of code, but as one network engineer to another  check out the code below.

A few more bits to bear in mind - You need to "establish adjacency" first (*exchange some hello packets*) or your PIM joins will get ignored by the upstream router (hence the dummy hello function added).

Furthermore, the "Upstream Neighbour IP" is also necessary when sending PIM joins.

```
import socket
from struct import pack, iter_unpack
from functools import reduce    

def checksum(data):
    sum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, iter_unpack("!H",data))
    s = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, sum)

    while (s >> 16):
        s = (s & 0xFFFF) + (s >> 16)
    s = ~s & 0xffff

    return s

def send_dummy_hello():
    PIM_GROUP = '224.0.0.13'

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_PIM)
    my_packet=pack('!BBH3H4H4H4H', 32, 0, 24707, 1, 2, 105, 20, 4, 16121,
        16078, 19, 4, 0, 1, 21, 4, 256, 0)

    sock.sendto(my_packet, (PIM_GROUP,0))

def send_dummy_join(group, rp_addr, neighbor_ip):
    PIM_GROUP = '224.0.0.13'

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_PIM)

    pim_ver    = 35
    pim_res    = 0
    pktchksum  = 0
    pim_opts   = 256
    neighbor   = socket.inet_aton(neighbor_ip)
    ngroups    = 1
    holdtime   = 210
    subnet     = socket.inet_aton('1.0.0.32')
    group_a    = socket.inet_aton(group)
    num_joins  = 1
    num_prunes = 0
    rrp_subnet = socket.inet_aton('1.0.7.32')
    rp_address = socket.inet_aton(rp_addr)

    my_packet = pack('!BB2H4sHH4s4sHH4s4s', pim_ver, pim_res, pktchksum, pim_opts,
        neighbor, ngroups, holdtime, subnet, group_a, num_joins, num_prunes, 
        rrp_subnet, rp_address)

    pktchksum = checksum(my_packet)
    my_packet = pack('!BB2H4sHH4s4sHH4s4s', pim_ver, pim_res, pktchksum, pim_opts,
        neighbor, ngroups, holdtime, subnet, group_a, num_joins, num_prunes, 
        rrp_subnet, rp_address)

    sock.sendto(my_packet, (PIM_GROUP,0))
    print (f'PIM Join sent to {neighbor_ip} for {group} & RP {rp_addr}')

>>>send_dummy_hello() 
>>>send_dummy_join('239.10.20.30','192.168.0.1','10.0.0.102')
```

I tested this with EVE-NG and it (magically!) worked :-)

**EDIT**:

The code is now edited to support header checksum calculation. I think this is now complete! :-)

Comment: Hey this is great! It absolutely did the job and it will be amazing if we can get the checksum calculated within the script.

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. Thank you so very much. I did some tests and it works a treat. Thank you!!!